# Asynchronous method in a loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas

I have a method which creates a canvas and draws images passed to it on the canvas. I pass an array called images which is an array of strings. Each string is a base64 image. Code is:

```
    function createCanvas(images) {

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = 600;
            canvas.height = gates.length * 200;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            images.forEach(function(imgData, index){

                    var img = new Image();

                    img.setAttribute('width', '180');
                    img.setAttribute('height', '180');
                    img.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/  png;base64,' + imgData);

                    img.onload = function() {
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 400, 10 + (index * 200), 180, 180);
                    };    
            });

        return canvas;
}
```

The problem is of course that onload() is asynchronous so canvas doesn't contained the drawn images when its returned. Whats the best way to resolve this? Could I use a promise here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534549/how-do-you-deal-with-html5s-canvas-image-load-asynchrony

Comment: Have you tried to wrap your function in $timeout ?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921743/image-preloading-in-canvas).

Comment: @naortor thanks, that works